# Class-visibility in eclipse plugin-project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, visibility

I am working on an eclipse plugin with the following structure:

- `my.plugin.one`
- `my.plugin.one.ui`
- `my.plugin.two`
- `my.plugin.three`
- `my.plugin.three.ui`

Inside `my.plugin.one.ui` I have a class `MyFirstClass` and inside `my.plugin.one` `MySecondClass`.

I now would like to use an instance of `MyFirstClass` in `MySecondClass` but it is not visible. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to export your package in the plugin you want to expose (`my.plugin.one.ui`) :

- Open your `MANIFEST.MF` file,
- `runtime` tab,
- then `add...` button
  and add the package you want to expose, the other plugin should be
  able to see it

If you  didn't do it, you also need to add a dependencies :

- Go to your other plugin (`my.plugin.one`) and open your `MANIFEST.MF` file,
- `dependencies` tab,
- and `add...` button, select the the plugin `my.plugin.one.ui`

Comment: Thank you very much @flafoux! This solved my problem.